# Multi Platform Website with Parallax Background

Tags: javascript, html

I have a request for a website with a lightly animated (Parallax) background. With full IE8 support. And if possible tablet support (such as iPads and android tablets).

Pick two of those and it would be easy enough to do but trying to encompass all three is a bit daunting... Does any one know what languages/technologies would cover all three of those requests?

Comment: All you need is Javascript and CSS. In my experience, if you optimise it well enough to run reasonably smoothly on a first-generation iPad, that's good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parallax, comes in 2 flavors, horizontal & vertical.
For horizontal parallax, you only need CSS and 2 or 3 background images positioned in %.
Vertical parallax on the other hand, you need JavaScript.

Then i would rethink the horizontal parallax effect on tablets, because you only see a horizontal parallax if you resize the browser window, that seems not quite possible on a tablet.

But i guess you will do a vertical:
If you do a vertical parallax with JavaScript, you can cover all devices.

Answer (score 3):

I'm working on a similar project. iOS doesn't support the normal parallax methods, because the browser usually freezes scripts and transitions during scroll events.

However, if you use [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) to handle the scrolling, you can override that and get fairly smooth parallax effects on iPhone and iPad.

IE doesn't support CSS transitions, so you'll need a purely javascript powered parallax plugin. I use Ian Lunn's [jQuery Parallax](http://www.ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/) though I suspect its not terribly efficient. (I've got *a lot* of moving elements and although it looks fine in Chrome, it looks like my computer is sitting on a paint mixer in IE.)